# display protected copyright video in my app

Tags: android, google-play, copyright-display

hi my question is can i display cartoon (like tom and Jerry .etc) in my app and use ads but only if the

user is connected to internet because the default is that i target specific niche

for users who want to watch cartoons without internet access and also i'm providing

privacy policy and disclaimer in the app i saw many examples in play store in the

last 3 months and many of these apps has 100+ thousandth downloads so

is it ok am i break any of play store policies here or is it fine ..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal issues, not about programming. Therefore, out of place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most certainly not fine.

> We don’t allow apps or developer accounts that infringe on the
>   intellectual property rights of others (including trademark,
>   copyright, patent, trade secret, and other proprietary rights). We
>   also don’t allow apps that encourage or induce infringement of
>   intellectual property rights.

https://play.google.com/about/ip-impersonation/ip/